# In what situation people type mobile number to send app download link?

Tags: mobile

Instead of just showing app download button, why to ask for mobile no. here is screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main reasons this occur, one for the business and the other for the user:

1. The company in question gets the users number to use for marketing purposes, to send promotional texts and offers directly to users.
2. Its makes it easier and more convenient for the user to download rather than having to search and find it on the app store. Thus increasing conversion (whatever that measurement maybe, downloads, data collation, app store ratings etc).

They could just as easily link to the app store but this is a cleverer way of harvesting data from users by offering a reward in the form of a quick way to get to the app. Then they can potentially get more data via the sign up process.

Comment: Can u pls re read question

Comment: My answer explains why there isn't a simple download button as per the context added in the description. Or are you looking for where and in what context this method of downloading the app may occur?

Comment: sorry i changed question little bit so wanted you to go through it again.

Comment: Still not good question, as obvious answer is "They type it, when they want to receive app download link"

Comment: The change in the question hasn't made any difference, if you're not getting the answers you want it might be worth re-wording the question again and/or adding more context in the description and people can answer/edit answers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to download app via sms than to search for it in the store. Maybe they want to have your phone number also.

Comment: Read question againa

Comment: @jivan When 2 different people provided answers but according to you didn't  understand your question, maybe the problem is the question? Could you explain in more details what kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: sorry i changed question little bit so wanted you to go through it again.